# No console output when running LuaJava Hello, World program

Tags: java, lua, luajava

I'm starting out to learn Lua script usage in Java via LuaJava; my IDE is Eclipse.

But when I execute this simple Hello World snippet there is no output in the Eclipse console.

Took the code snippet from [here](http://w3.impa.br/~rbs/pdf/GAMEON-NA07.pdf)

```
package com.cpg.lua;

import org.keplerproject.luajava.LuaState;
import org.keplerproject.luajava.LuaStateFactory;

public class Hello
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
  LuaState luaState;
  luaState = LuaStateFactory.newLuaState();
  luaState.openLibs();
  luaState.LdoFile("hello.lua");
  luaState.close();
}
}
```

**hello.lua**

```
function hello()
    print("Hello World from Lua!") 
end

hello()
```

But the script beneath works perfectly well.

**hello2.lua**

```
print("Hello World from Lua!")
```

Anyone know why the script with the function definition inside does nothing when called from Java but when executed through the console works perfectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried or seen a function called like that. But you can call the `hello()` function from the Java like this:

```
LuaState l = LuaStateFactory.newLuaState();
l.doFile("main.lua");
l.getGlobal("hello");
l.call(0, 0);
```